# JPA @OneToMany with out Db constaraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Asking if this is Possible Or Impossible

Can we Create Java JPA Mapping "@OneToMany" without having DB constraint such as PrimaryKey , ForeignKey creation on the Db table ?

Reason

When creating a normal SQL Query we JOIN 2 Tables by the Column constrains ( if equals ) with out creating PK or FK constrains .

Comment: Yes, you can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can refer to a column that is not a PK. And you can ask Hibernate to not create a FK:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "not_an_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
private Owner owner;
```

Comment: Thx for this valuable info... more on ask is 
Can @OneToMany  annotation be applied on Non PK column on a One Table in reference to Non PK or FK Column on second Table ...similarly....